# Gausian 09 error: NtrErr Called from FileIO

Tags: gaussian

I got below mentioned error while trying to optimise a Ru transition metal complex using
6-311++G(d,p)

Can you please assist me to resolve this problem

```
Error termination in NtrErr:
 NtrErr Called from FileIO.`

 Number            698           701           710           711           780           989
 Base          4650052       4650400       2276811       3677828       9027123       2037482
 End           4650400       4772209       2280541       4130096       9978828       2057482
 End1          4650400       4772209       2280541       4130096       9978828       2057482
 Wr Pntr       4650052       4650400       2276811       3677828       9027123       2037482
 Rd Pntr       4650052       4650400       2276811       3677828       9978828       2037482
 Length            348        121809          3730        452268        951705         20000

 Number            993           997           998
 Base          2057482       2057682         40990
 End           2057682       2058800         41190
 End1          2057682       2058800         41190
 Wr Pntr       2057482       2057682         40990
 Rd Pntr       2057482       2057682         41190
 Length            200          1118           200


 dumping /fiocom/, unit = 3 NFiles =     1 SizExt =    524288 WInBlk =      1024
                   defal = T LstWrd =       65536 FType=2 FMxFil=10000

 Number              0
 Base            40960
 End             65536
 End1            65536
 Wr Pntr         40960
 Rd Pntr         40960
 Length          24576
 Error termination in NtrErr:
 NtrErr Called from FileIO.
"NeutralB3LYPmethanoloptimizationCl6-311+gdprestart.log" 3353L, 226558
```

The input file:

```
%mem=4GB
%nprocshared=4
%chk=NeutralB3LYPmethanoloptimizationCl6-311+gdprestart.chk
# opt freq b3lyp/genecp scrf=(solvent=methanol) guess=save
geom=connectivity

Neutral Fluoride Complex from the X-ray crystal structure
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! If possible, please include the output file (or as many lines as you can preceding the error) as a code block in your question. This will make it easier to see what part of the calculation led to this error.

Comment: I have added few other lines in the output

Comment: Googling your error message gives quite a few hits, https://www.researchgate.net/post/Error-termination-in-NtrErr-NtrErr-called-from-FIOCnC-How-this-error-could-be-solved is the first one which suggests it may be a checkpoint file problem, others seem to refer to running out of disk space. I'm not a Gaussian user so I can't say more, but a a general hint googling the error message is general a pretty good first step.

Comment: Actually I tried those suggestions and couldn't fix the problem yet.

Comment: From [this](https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/Gaussian_error_messages) site, the problem is: _This typically happens when you try to retrieve something from the checkpoint file (with Opt=ReadFC or guess=read or geom=allcheck/modify) that is not there, either because you did not calculate it previously, or you ran out of disk space or time while running the earlier job and the information needed wasn't written to the checkpoint file._ and the solution _Re-calculate or type in the information required._

Comment: I think Camps is on the right track. Was this calculation an attempt to restart a previous one? Are you intending to use `guess=save`, which saves the initial guess for the MO coefficients/density to the checkpoint file in the case of `guess=only` calculation?

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.